# where is the template (zip file) for WCF Rest Service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, wcf-rest, project-template

I've been working on a process for programmatically generating Visual Studio projects using GetProjectTemplate.  You provide GetProjectTemplate the name of the template (a .zip file like "MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplatev3.01.cshtml.zip") and the language ("csharp").

Here's the path to MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplatev3.01.cshtml.zip

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache\CSharp\Web\1033\MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplatev3.01.cshtml.zip

I'm trying to find the template name for WCF Rest Service Application.  It's the same template used by Visual Studio when creating a new WCF Rest Service project.  I've looked all around where MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplatev3.01.cshtml.zip is saved and cannot find anything that resembles WCF Rest Service template.

Thanks  Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is an extension and because of that it is not part of Visual installation (that is affected only by separately installed products). You will find the template under your user profile:

```
"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions\Microsoft\WCF REST Service Template 40(CS)"
```